# Capture and assert Meta tags in RSpec

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am trying to write a unit test to assert few meta tag values (under  section of the response). How can I use the attribute tag to check individual value?
Ex:

```
<meta property="keyword" content="site keywords" />
<meta property="description" content="site description" />
```

So far this is all I got. But it comes back as failed.

```
it "should check meta fields" do
  get :show, {:format => 'html' }
  r = response.body
  r.should have_selector('meta', :content => @site.title)
end
```

Comment: What is the value of `@site.title`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Capybara's `have_selector` matcher takes an option `:text`, not `:content`:

```
r.should have_selector('meta', :text => @site.title)
```

See [this discussion](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/478) and [this discussion](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/525) on github.

However, that doesn't explain why your spec fails, since the `:content` option is ignored and should make your test if anything *more* permissive.

The most likely reason this test is failing is that it is being called from a controller spec, in which case the response will be blank because rspec-rails [prevents rails from actually rendering views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063073/rspec-controller-testing-blank-response-body). If this is the case, you will need to either move the spec to a file under spec/requests/, or add the directive [`render_views`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-0/docs/controller-specs/render-views) just inside the `describe` block.

If that doesn't work then you'll have to provide more information on the context for the spec, otherwise it's hard to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Both meta tags in the author's example have no value (`property` and `content` are attributes), so it's needed to match against those attributes. Perhaps my answer below helps.

Answer (score 2):

To assert `<meta>` tag:

```
have_selector 'meta[property=keyword][content="site keywords"]', visible: false
```

For `<title>` Capybara has a built-in matcher:

```
have_title 'The title of my website'
```